# swftools not compiling on Linux 32bit

Tags: amazon-ec2, 32bit-64bit

I get the following error when trying to compile swftools-0.9.1 or the current source on a EC2 small instance (which is only 32bit):

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ubuntu/src/swftools-2010-10-12-2000/lib'
gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -I/usr/include/freetype2 -fPIC -Wimplicit -Wreturn-type -Wno-write-strings -Wformat -O -fomit-frame-pointer  modules/swfaction.c -o modules/swfaction.o
In file included from modules/.././bitio.h:23,
                 from modules/../rfxswf.h:37,
                 from modules/swfaction.c:24:
modules/.././types.h:39:2: error: #error "no way to define 64 bit integer"
modules/.././types.h:42:2: error: #error "don't know how to define 32 bit integer"
modules/.././types.h:45:2: error: #error "don't know how to define 16 bit integer"
modules/.././types.h:48:2: error: #error "don't know how to define 8 bit integer"
make[1]: *** [modules/swfaction.o] Error 1
```

Was support for not 64-bit capable Linux(ubuntu) removed?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the exact same error when trying to compile it under Fedora 14.

When I looked at the config.log file in the root of the build tree, I saw the following error:

"error while loading shared libraries: libpdf.so.6: cannot enable executable stack as shared object requires: Permission denied"

Which lead me to this thread:  http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tools.swftools.general/1452 (I've replied with my solution there as well.)

Sadly, no one there had any real answers as well, save that someone was able to build it successfully..

What I had to do is:

sudo setsebool allow_execstack on

And things built just fine, eliminating that error entirely.

However, the other solution is that you may simply be missing a devel library, such as the FreeType headers, since I don't think Ubuntu uses SELinux. (Though I could be wrong)

For the record, here's the development headers I have on my 32 bit Fedora box where this compiles fine:

zlib-devel, jpeglib-turbo-devel (a Fedora 14 specific lib, but jpeglib-devel should work in other distros), libpng-devel, giflib-devel, pdflib-lite-devel, freetype-devel, fontconfig-devel

Lastly, I'm using swftools-0.9.1 (latest stable at the time of this writing).  My advice would be to look at the config.log file and grep for 'error' and try to resolve any outstanding entries. Especially ones returned from ld.

Answer (score 1):

I did have exactly same problem. I just run following command and after that compiled without any problems..

```
sudo yum install libjpeg-devel giflib-devel freetype-devel zlib-devel jpeglib-devel libpng-devel giflib-devel pdflib-lite-devel freetype-devel fontconfig-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you followed the [steps here](http://www.betaquest.com/2010/08/how-to-install-swftools-0-9-1-on-centos-5-5/)

I also had the same problem and the exact error. I tried to install jpeglib from the source code and it was little annoying bcos it is not detecting by swftools configure script and given following output -
* The following headers/libraries are missing: ungif freetype gif_lib.h
* Disabling pdf2swf tool…
* Disabling gif2swf tool…

Also I followed the steps mentioned in swftools installation (http://wiki.swftools.org/index.php?title=Installation) but didn’t work. Then I installed the libjpeg-devel, giflib-devel, freetype-devel packages using yum which was [mentioned here](http://www.betaquest.com/2010/08/how-to-install-swftools-0-9-1-on-centos-5-5/.)
Then ./configure executed without disabling the pdf2swf tool and gif2swf tool. Finally I ran make & it was given the exact error you attached above. So I ran make clean and make uninstall commands in jpeglib extracted source directory and finally ran make in swftools directory. It worked with no errors...